# Changing file associations using Java

Tags: java, windows, cmd, registry, file-association

I have read that you can change the Windows file associations by using commands like `assoc .pmdtb="X:\PassswordManager.bat"`, but I still have some problems with it.

1. When I run the command in the command line, then nothing changes. Files with this extension are still opened with Notepad.
2. When I try to run the command in Java, I am denied access.

How do I edit the Windows internal file associations in Java? If I should rather edit the registry directly, which of the many Classes directories?

My Java code:

```java
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c assoc .pmdtb=\"X:\\PasswordManager.bat\"");
// --> Access denied.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess you merged your knowledge of `assoc` and `ftype`. See the help for both commands.

Comment: Thank you. So do I need to create a `ftype` with the path first and assign the `ftype` to the file extension under `assoc`?

Comment: it doesn't matter, which you do first. They just have to match `assoc .pmdtb=PwdFile` and `ftype pmdtb="X:\PasswordManager.bat" %1` (probably - depends on what the script expects)

Comment: I tried using `assoc .pmdtb=passwordmanagerdatabase` and `ftype passwordmanagerdatabase="X:\PasswordManager.bat" %1` in my shell. I don't know if I am using it wrong, but .pmdtb files are still opened with the notepad if not further specified. Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File associations will apparently no longer be changeable with `assoc` and `ftype` starting with Windows 8. A hash code is additionally in the registry, which is generated with a secret algorithm. If I change the file association, but the hash does not match, the default opening of this file extension will not change. The Windows algorithm for the hash has been reverse engineered. Based on this, you could translate the algorithm into Java and change the registry directly.

The C++ code with QT can be found here: https://pastebin.com/yVhWeQ3X

Answer (score 0):

By far the simplest method is to use one of many FTA utilities that resolve the security hash for you.

For example https://danysys.com/set-file-type-association-default-application-command-line-windows-10-userchoice-hash-internal-method/

Then use that via a cmd line call from your java app

You may need to test out the options (read the comments on linked page above and review [issues on github](https://github.com/DanysysTeam/SFTA/issues?q=is%3Aissue)) however it could be as simple as

```
SFTA.exe --reg "X:\PassswordManager.bat" "pmdtb"
```